# Is "disguise" used correctly?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Is it correct to use "disguised" as in this sentence...

> The economic boom in India DISGUISED the religious conflicts in many states.

...or should I use instead "veiled", "masked", "concealed", "obscured", or something else?

I feel that all these alternatives are somewhat wrong. The intended meaning is that the conflicts became temporarily less strong as a result of the booming economy, and hence became temporarily less visible, but were still latent and would reapper with all their strength in the economic depression that would follow the boom.

Would you know of any better word to replace "disguised" if "disguised" is wrongly used?

Comment: 'Disguise' means to make something look like something else. I prefer 'obscured'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you say that using "obscured" is 100% solid in that context? It reads somewhat awkward to me but I am not native so how something feels to me is of little importance...

Comment: There are others: overshadowed.

Comment: Thank you. My concern with "overshadowed" is that it conveys that the economic boom appeared more prominent or important than the conflicts, and that's not exactly what I am trying to say.

Comment: @pierrot5 How did it obscure them without appearing more prominent than them?

Comment: The idea that I am trying to convey is that it hid them a bit. I am more focused on that negative aspect than on the opposite positive one. Does it make sense?

Comment: _Masked_ or _concealed_ seem OK to me.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that the subject that conceals should always be a person and cannot be something (like an "economic boom").

Answer (score 0):

I changed my answer here after reading your comments about your intent. My understanding is you're not saying they eased conflicts or made them better, but rather made them less noticeable because of the economic boom.

Given what you said you mean, perhaps you should state it differently. For example:

> The economic boom in India diverted attention away from the religious conflicts in many states.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. "To divert attention" is not exactly what I am trying to say. It is my fault. I did not explain myself properly. I am not native in English. It is difficult for me to describe things properly. I have edited the main question. What I am trying to say is something like this: *The intended meaning is that the conflicts became temporarily less strong as a result of the booming economy, and hence became temporarily less visible, but were still latent and would reapper with all their strength in the economic depression that would follow the boom.*

Comment: I feel that *concealed*, *masked*, *disguised*, *obscured* or *veiled* might be appropriate words, but I cannot tell with native certainty if they are idiomatic and appropriate in this situation. Maybe there is a better word.

Comment: PS: I don't think that there is a word that can encapsulate all of that long intended meaning. I am just looking for one that points in that direction and doesn't exclude it.

Comment: Maybe something like *temporarily concealed* is appropriate?